# How c library function stored in memory?

Tags: c, memory, operating-system

I have a pretty good understanding of how functions stored on stack. But i couldn't find anything related to how OS manage library functions such as c library.

for example, system() in stdlib.h.
When main calls system() or any other c function,

where does it stored? does it push another function frame on stack(i doubt it)?

or is it stored in heap? is there a table stores location of each function in c library? if so, when does this table constructed?
how do we get there? how do we get back?

and if we create our library, does OS treat it the same way?

Is there a different between static library and shared library in this matter?

Can someone explain with a simple example?

Thank you in advance, this bothers me quite a bit lately.

Comment: I think you're confusing two unrelated things. The CODE of the function is either loaded into memory when the program starts (if it's linked statically), or loaded when first called (from a shared library/dll). When the function is called, a stack frame is created for the DATA--the function arguments and its local variables. The OS manages how memory is allocated and what parts are used for code and which for data and stack. Functions in shared libraries/dlls also have the advantage that if they are called from a second program, the already-loaded code is reused.

Comment: Officially, I don't believe C actually defines any of this stuff. It's OS/compiler/linker dependent; in practice, there are a few common patterns, but C doesn't require any given approach. And in practice, @LeeDanielCrocker's explanation is slightly oversimplified; the statically linked code is *mapped* into memory on launch, but not necessarily *loaded* (could be demand paged on use), and shared libs/DLLs might be eagerly mapped, lazily mapped based on trampoline code, or explicitly loaded during execution (without being mapped on launch at all).

Comment: Your program will have diffrent segments - code segment ,data segment,stack segment,extra segment - All functions will be in code segment

Comment: *I have a pretty good understanding of how functions stored on stack*, I really doubt that. I think you need to revisit the basics.

Comment: You should not care at all. Your question is unclear, and shows a lot of confusion. Read some book like http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/

Answer (score 2):

In general it all is not related to the type of the library used. Any operating system loads your executable program and libraries into memory. This is the task of the operating system loader and linker to figure out where to load all of them. All details are hidden from generic applications. All they see is the memory space where different regions of memory are used differently.

Your program consists of 2 parts: data and machine instructions which operate on data and provides services. All instructions as well as data are allocated in memory and can be addressed, if you know where to look.

So, the function is a piece of code which starts at a particular address in memory. When your program calls a function it just executes a jump instruction to that address. When function is done, it jumps  back to the instruction next after the original jump.

The instructions in the function do operate on data allocated somewhere in memory as well. It is a convention that when a function gets called, it reserves a piece of memory for local data, so that its instruction can operate on this memory, called `stack`. So, strictly speaking, the function itself is not allocated on stack, instead it uses stack to keep its local data. When the function returns, it releases the stack memory it used, so that the latter could be used by some other function. If a function is called multiple times, it reserves new memory space for its local data for every call. This is basically what stack is.

Heap is different from the stack only by its usage and allocation algorithm. It is not related to the function call and heap memory regions can be requested by the program at will, when they are needed.

There is also a static memory space, which is reserved by the system loader together with instructions, and intended for static variables. Its size is known at compilation time and therefore, no dynamic allocation is needed for these vars.

All these memory regions are parts of the same memory pool and differ only in usage and reservation algorithms. However, if one wants, the program instructions could be stored in heap or in stack or in static space. This usually is used by hackers. One can also create its own memory allocation mechanisms if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Library functions are no different to functions defined in your code - they are simply provided already compiled.  A function's local, not-static *data* is stored on the stack, not the function itself.

For static libraries references to the library code are resolved at build time, and the code itself included in the fully linked executable - by the linker.

For shared or dynamic-linked libraries, the library code is loaded into memory and linked to your code at run-time by the operating system loader.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a big question and the answer depends upon the operating system.

If the library is static, the functions are linked into the executable image. They get loaded into memory along with the rest of the executable.

If it is a shared image, there are two common paths. Some operating systems keep standard libraries always open that they are actually shared among processes using them. In that case,the operating system maps the pages containing the shared library to the process address space.

Another possible path is that the shared libraries is loaded identically to the executable. The program loader gets called recursively for each shared library referenced (directly or indirectly) by the executable.

> When main calls system() or any other c function, where does it stored?

Wherever the program loader has placed it in memory.

> does it push another function frame on stack(i doubt it)?
>   The stack has nothing to do with code.
>
> or is it stored in heap?

Heap is just an abstract concept for teaching.

> is there a tables stores location of each function in c library?

A shared library maintains such a table.

> if so, when does this table constructed?

A table is created by the linker. Usually, this information is also preserved in memory by the program loader.

> how do we get there?

The executable format will define where the universal symbol mapping is found.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a static version of the standard library, then the functions are treated exactly the same as regular functions. However, if you are using a dynamic version of the standard library, then the functions are most likely already pre-loaded in the operating system you are using in a memory location separate from that of your program (most likely, because they are loaded into the operating system's memory only once a program uses the function. Subsequent uses of the function by different programs does not require the function to be re-loaded into memory).

Comment: Your answer doesn't address the OP question of how an OS manages library functions.